# Error - "Gradle DSL method not found: compile()" while adding recyclerview

Tags: android

I want to use recyclerview in my app. I added "complie 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'" in app level build.gradle file. Getting error -
Error:(26, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'complie()'
Possible causes:

The project 'Rview' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

here my build.gradle file-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sid.rview"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
complie 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while copying compile links from any website , please write **compile** by yourself as many websites have different character encoding than android studio. mostly this problem is only for that first **c** in **compile** method

Comment: Thanks man, it worked